# Pytest not working after creating file inside folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

This is the structure of my project:

```
.
|--- conftest.py
|--- /tools
|---|--- /file_parser
|---|--- |--- process_files.py
|---|--- |--- generate_files.py
|-- /test
|--|--- test_generate_files.py
...
```

From my root directory, i am running `python -m pytest` and i am getting an import error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named process_files.py`. There is only `test_generate_files.py` test to run, and in the beginning of this file, i import:

```py
from tools.file_parser import generate_files
```

I am not using `process_files.py` in my tests yet, so i don't know what is causing this error. The only workaround i found that made it work was adding  `tools` as a module in my `PYTHONPATH`, but i'd like to know if there's any other way.

I also tried adding `__init__.py` in the `/test` folder, as also adding to the `/tools` and `/file_parser` as well. Couldn't make it work. Doing some research, i found out that adding `conftest.py` in the root would manage this problem, but it was not the case.

ps: Tests were running successfully before creating `process_file.py`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you share the contents of `generate_files.py`?

Comment: `generate_files.py` has some imports, functions and a `if __name__=='__main__'` that calls one of those functions.

Comment: What are the imports?

Comment: general libraries: `sklearn`, `pandas`, `ntlk`, `json`, etc. Nothing related to the current folder.